# Python source files not extracted when I pip install my package

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I've created some small and simple python package and uploaded it to the PYPI.
When I install my package using pip install, everything works fine,
but the python source files are not extracted, the installed-files.txt file does not   include it.
SOURCES.txt DOES include the python source file.
Only __init__.py file is extracted.

I can not understand what is wrong with my package or the way I create it.
Please advice....

My package name is **test_pypi**
You can find it here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/test_pypi
Package has no requirements

Package folder contains following files:

- __init__.py - empty file
- LICENSE.txt - contains Apache license
- MANIFEST.in

  ```
  include READMT.rst  
  include LICENSE.txt  
  recursive-include test_pypi/mdl *.py
  ```
- setup.py

  ```
  from setuptools import setup

  def readme():
  with open('README.rst') as f:
          return f.read()

  setup(name='test_pypi',
      version='1.0',
      description='test_pypi_description',
      url='https://pypi.python.org/pypi/test_pypi',
      license='LICENSE.txt',
      author='Evgeny Fedoruk',
      author_email='minievg@hotmail.com',
      packages=['test_pypi'],
      install_requires=[],
      zip_safe=False)
  ```

The package folder (test_pypi) contains:

- __init__.py - empty file
- mdl (folder) contains

  - empty __init__.py file
  - python source file *test.py*

    ```
    print 'hello'
    ```

I do the following for uploading the package:

```
python setup.py register sdist upload
```

I do the following for installing it:

```
pip install test_pypi
```

One last thing, I tried installing it with virtual env and without it - same problem, the *test.py* file is not extracted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include mdl in your `packages` argument to setup():

`packages=['test_pypi','test_pypi.mdl'],`

Packages you want to include must either be explicitly listed, or you can have setuptools find them using find_packages() :

```
from setuptools import find_packages
my_packages=find_packages()
```