# Hello World Python Module Not Importing From PyPi

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with a python package that I just created. I added it to PyPi, but for some reason after I pip install the package, it successfully imports the package but when I go to access the one function I created it cannot find that function. So when I try to import hello_world it does not work.

My package is structured as follows:

```
Hello World Package/
   setup.py
   hello_world/
      __init__.py
      hello_world.py
```

**My scripts:**

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

VERSION = "0.0.1"
DESCRIPTION = "Test"

setup(
    name="hello_world_jalvini",
    version=VERSION,
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description="LONG_DESCRIPTION",
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    keywords=["python"],
    py_modules=["hello_world"],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    ]
)
```

`hello_world/__init__.py`

```
from .hello_world import *
```

hello_world/hello_world.py

```
def hello_world():
    print('Hello World')
```

Project Location On PyPi:

https://pypi.org/project/hello-world-jalvini/

Comment: How did you try to import the one function? What was the error message including traceback?

Comment: Well, in the IDE its saying Import "hello_world_jalvini" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports and when I got to run it, it is saying line 1, in <module>
    from hello_world_jalvini import hello_world
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello_world_jalvini'

Comment: I have tried importing it numerous ways and it just cannot find the package. My end goal is to have my function import as easily as a funciton can be imported in numpy or any other package. I just want to be able to pip install it and then reference the method.

Comment: The Python package is called `hello_world`, not `hello_world_jalvini`. And the function `hello_world` is contained in the `hello_world.hello_world` module.

Comment: Im still not getting it. Its throwing: Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'hello_world'

Comment: Okay, I installed your package from pip and it seems there is no code in it. Probably this is your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543705/python-source-files-not-extracted-when-i-pip-install-my-package

Comment: @mkrieger1 please add your comment as an answer below so I can give you credit. It turns out that you were right. Right after I figured out that the package was empty I realized that I hadn’t added packages to my setup.py. As soon as I did, it now adds the hello world folder to my packages. And thank you for the help.